# customize odoo portal home page

Tags: python, odoo

I am using openerp 8 with the portal module to get a custom home page for the clients

I want to show to the clients all their product which I can display it using the clients id 
and the normal controller doesn't work for me

```
@http.route('/home',auth='user',website=True,type="http")
```

My problem is how can I get the client id which has login to the system?

This is the homepage which i want to modify it: [my homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQajT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your client id from request object.
ie, `uid = request.session.uid`

Comment: what is the differenec between request.uid and request.session.uid

Comment: When the user is not logged in, you will get an id while using request.uid, is default portal user id, should be 3 or 1, according to version it varies